# Unable to stop YouTube video using jQuery on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, youtube, youtube-javascript-api

For a website I am developing, I need to stop youtube videos(embedded using iframe) when a particular event occurs.

So I tried some sample jQuery(very rough, so forgive me:P) as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head>     
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>     
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/C0DPdy98e4c?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="Stop" id="btnStop"/>    
<script>
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#btnStop').click(function(){
        $('iframe')[0].contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify({
            "event" : "command",
            "func" : "stopVideo",
            "args" : ""
        }),"https://www.youtube.com");
      });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But the video stops **only works on Chrome and firefox**. It **doesn't stop on IE**. I tried on IE 11 and 10.

I know there are many questions around here regarding stopping youtube iframe and I have gone through most of them. But I cannot figure out where I'm wrong.

Or if this cannot work in IE, can you give me any other suggestion(other than youtube api)?

So I would appreciate any help you guys can give me!!

**EDIT**: Please try this link - https://www.googledrive.com/host/0B58rEiAJ1HiaeEU2eWNHem5WM0U

Comment: does changing `$(window).load()` to `$(document).ready()` change the behavior?

Comment: No, I had tried that earlier.

Comment: what is the issue? Do you have errors in browser console?

Comment: Oops, sorry I think I didn't mention that properly. The video doesn't stop on IE.

Comment: Is the problem that your stopVideo function is not working, or that you can't get your click() handler to work in IE?

Comment: The click event is firing. But the youtube stopVideo/pauseVideo functions etc are not working. I suspected it might be because of contentWindow.postMessage, but it is supported in IE 8+

Comment: can you put this into jsfiddle

Comment: The video [appears to stop](http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/veyuboy6/) for me on IE 11...

Comment: Hi Jonathan, yes it looks like the jsFiddle is working in IE11. But the actual html is not. Please try this link : https://www.googledrive.com/host/0B58rEiAJ1HiaeEU2eWNHem5WM0U

Comment: @darkdef That page also works for me in Internet Explorer 11. Do you have all updates installed? What version of IE are you running? I am testing with 11.0.9600.17498.

Answer (score 1):

why not this?

[image: vid]

```
  $('#btnStop').click(function(e){
    $('iframe')[0].src = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/C0DPdy98e4c?enablejsapi=1';
  });
```

Edit: to pause it, this seems to work well for me

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#btnStop').on('click', function(){
        $('iframe')[0].contentWindow
          .postMessage('{'+
             '"event":"command",'+
             '"func":"pauseVideo"'+
             ',"args":""}','*');
    });
});
```

html

```
<div>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/C0DPdy98e4c?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<input type="button" value="stop" id="btnStop"/>
```

Comment: Hi Todd, Thanks for the suggestion. Though this works, I still don't understand why my js is not working on IE. Suppose I want to pauseVideo instead of stop, this will not work.

Comment: @darkdef check out the EDIT which **has** been confirmed to work in IE